# Setting up "Application uses WiFi" property in info plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, info.plist

I was trying to set "Application uses WiFi" property in my application info plist but to my surprise, I was not able to find this property in the info plist.

The XCODE version I am using is 3.2.6 and IOS is 4.3.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can open your info.plist file as source code and then add this

```
<key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
<true/>
```

Before the `</dict>` tag

Comment: Instead of "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" I am getting "LSRequiresCarbon" option.

Comment: Is it UIRequires or LSRequires?